# what will bemachine learning algorithm for sorting the PC configuration

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

I am pretty new to machine learning algorithms. I was handed over a project to use machine learning.I am basically given 2000 elements of data. The data contains 7 elements required to build a pc:Ram,cpu,gpu,keyboard,mouse,screen,hdd. Each components cost is given and each components performance.We need to select one from each component like 1 ram,1 screen,1 gpu,1 cpu,1 keyboard,1 mouse,1 graphic card. The user enters a budget and the machine learning algo needs to predict the configuration of pc with highest total performance under the budget.
I want to what kind of algorithm to use for this type of problem.
Any suggestions regarding algorithms.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be resolved with [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) instead of Machine Learning

Comment: I tried the using the knapsack but the problem with that is in knapsack we have all uniform data sets. that is we can select any data item in knapsack algo. But in our case we should atleast have one cpu,one keyboard etc. Do you know any way we can overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a machine learning problem. It is an optimization problem. Knapsack can be used with some alterations. Try adding constraints that the value of components can only be 1.